# figure not filling window python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, figure

So I'm trying to create 2D images based on a numpy array where the value is the intensity at x,y is the row/column of the array. The individual values in the array are generated by processing the radial profile of an image and then integrating over a certain range of radii. I get a list of 4096 values which I reshape into a 64x64 array then plot the array. This all worked fine and I got the figure that I was looking for, and made sure that it worked with my stack cleared. However, now when I run it without changing anything other than the range of the integration, also with a cleared stack, the figure doesn't generate properly. I tried changing back to the original limits and it now won't generate that either.

Instead of being a full figure window, the window appear and the image I want is situated in the bottom left corner, really small and I cannot resize it, zoom in, move it about or anything. If I try to save the image, it just saves the grey figure window with the image in the corner. [Example of the tiny image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/291sJ.png)

The code that is being used to process the image in this instance is,

```
def pixel(image,s,e):
    centre = CoM.centre_of_mass(image)
    rad = CoM.radial_profile (image, centre)
    sumRange = sp.integrate.simps(rad[s:e])
    return sumRange

results = []
for i in range(0,64):
        for j in range(0,64):
            results.append(CoM.pixel(im[i,j].data,30,60))

data = np.array(results)
fig = plt.figimage(data.reshape(64,64))
plt.show()
```

So my question is hence, did I do anything in my code/compiling that would have affected the image like this, and how do I solve it?

I tried using `tight_layout()` but `figimage()` doesn't have this as an attribute. I also tried using just a standard plt.plot() but I get a plot of each row of the array plotted as a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try `plt.imshow`. `plt.figimage` does not resample the image and draws it in unit of pixels. 
From the documentation of `figimage`:

> figimage complements the axes image (imshow()) which will be resampled to fit the current axes. If you want a resampled image to fill the entire figure, you can define an Axes with size [0,1,0,1].